# why do sql procedure retuns 0 rows when called from applciation?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have this procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadEquipments] null, 'Vessel'

    @Param varchar(30),    -- EquipmentNo
    @EqptType varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN

        IF((@Param is not null OR @Param != '') AND (@EqptType is not null OR @EqptType != ''))
        Begin
              select Functionallocation as 'EquipmentNo', WinFileno as 'Functionallocation', EqptType , 
              EquipmentDescription, TrainNo, PlantNo 'PlanGroup' , PlantNo 'WorkCenter' ,Area,  * from EngineeringData 
              where EqptType = @EqptType and Functionallocation = @Param
        End
        Else IF(@Param is not null OR @Param != '')
        Begin
              select Functionallocation as 'EquipmentNo', WinFileno as 'Functionallocation', EqptType , 
              EquipmentDescription, TrainNo, PlantNo 'PlanGroup' , PlantNo 'WorkCenter' ,Area,  * from EngineeringData 
              where Functionallocation = @Param
        End
        Else IF(@EqptType is not null OR @EqptType != '')
        Begin
              select Functionallocation as 'EquipmentNo', WinFileno as 'Functionallocation', EqptType , 
              EquipmentDescription, TrainNo, PlantNo 'PlanGroup' , PlantNo 'WorkCenter' ,Area,  * from EngineeringData 
              where EqptType = @EqptType
        End
        Else IF((@EqptType is null OR @EqptType = '') AND (@Param IS NOT NULL OR @Param != ''))
        Begin
              select Functionallocation as 'EquipmentNo', WinFileno as 'Functionallocation', EqptType , 
              EquipmentDescription, TrainNo, PlantNo 'PlanGroup' , PlantNo 'WorkCenter' ,Area,  * from EngineeringData 
              where FunctionalLocation = @Param
        End
        Else IF((@Param  = '' OR @Param is null) AND (@EqptType IS NOT NULL OR @EqptType != ''))
        Begin
              select Functionallocation as 'EquipmentNo', WinFileno as 'Functionallocation', EqptType , 
              EquipmentDescription, TrainNo, PlantNo 'PlanGroup' , PlantNo 'WorkCenter' ,Area,  * from EngineeringData 
              where EqptType = @EqptType
        End

END
```

If i send it params i.e. null, 'Vessel'. It returns 21 rows. That's ok but when I call from applcaition.

```
public DT_EquipmentResponseEquipment[] Equipments(DT_EquipmentRequest req)
    {
        try
        {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.EquipmentNumberFrom))
        {
            req.EquipmentNumberFrom = null;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.ObjectType[0]))
        {
            req.ObjectType[0] = null;
        }

        SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService c = new SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService();


        string strConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SAPConnection"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "ReadEquipments";

        //string[] arrObjTypes = MT_EquipmentRequest.ObjectType[9];
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = null; //req.EquipmentNumberFrom;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EqptType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "Vessel"; //req.ObjectType[0];

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);

        List<DT_EquipmentResponseEquipment> listResponse = new List<DT_EquipmentResponseEquipment>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtRecord.Rows)
        {
            DT_EquipmentResponseEquipment response = new DT_EquipmentResponseEquipment();

            response.EQUNR = Convert.ToString(dr["EquipmentNo"]);
            response.EQTYP = Convert.ToString(dr["EqptType"]);
            response.EQKTX = Convert.ToString(dr["EquipmentDescription"]);
            response.SWERK = Convert.ToString(dr["TrainNo"]);
            response.INGRP = Convert.ToString(dr["PlanGroup"]);
            response.LGWID = Convert.ToString(dr["WorkCenter"]);
            response.HEQUI = Convert.ToString(dr["Area"]);

            listResponse.Add(response);
        }



        return c.Equipment(req);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

For this it returns 0 rows even I am passing same params.

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = null; //req.EquipmentNumberFrom;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EqptType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "Vessel"; //req.ObjectType[0];
```

WHy? even same params nd same type but still not result from their using app. From raw pricedure it returns ok. I tried everything.

Comment: What is `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadEquipments] null, 'Vessel'`?

Comment: *"I tried everything."* So what is "everything"? If you *had* tried everything then there would be nothing left for us to offer you.

Comment: Aren't you getting an exception when you pass `null` to the SP instead of `DBNull.Value`?

Comment: Be careful here....you have performance time bomb on your hands. This type of query is going to suffer from periodic and random performance problems that will be difficult to figure out. Check out this article on this topic. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: Also, not a big deal but you can simplify checking for not null and not an empty string. You can just use @Param > ''. Also, look closely at your logic. You have some paths that you can't get to. The 4th and 5th conditions are not reachable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set null as a parameter value, use [DBNull.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.8)

```
   sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = DBNull.Value; //req.EquipmentNumberFrom;
```